# PHP Upload files showing 403 server error

Tags: php, image, upload, http-status-code-403

Getting this weird error on the server after trying to upload images with size greater than 20k. Images below that size will be uploaded successfully.

What is the problem?

by the way, the configuration in the `php.ini` is

```
upload_max_filesize = 96M
post_max_size = 96M
```

I am using `PHP 5.6`

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Could be many things. It may help if you provide a snippet of your code used for the upload. :)

Comment: believe me, nothing special there. Just a simple upload form and when the form getting post to the action. error appears

Comment: Could just be a permissions issue in the directory that the files are uploaded to.

Comment: It uploads the images below 20k size. only.
is that related to permissions issue ?

Comment: Probably not, unless your host doesn't support large file uploads. (I know some small hosts don't)

Answer (score 1):

There can be several causes for your problem. Please check all points listed here:

> The 403 Forbidden error is an HTTP status code which means that
>   accessing the page or resource you were trying to reach is absolutely
>   forbidden for some reason.

There are three common causes for this error. Here they are listed from most likely to least likely.

**Empty httpdocs directory**

Make sure that your website content has been uploaded to the correct directory on your server. Remember to replace example.com with your own domain name.

```
DV server: /var/www/vhosts/dv-example.com/httpdocs/
    When you connect with your FTP user, you just need to navigate into the httpdocs directory.
```

If this folder does not exist, feel free to create it.

**No index page**

The home page for your website must be called index.php or index.html.

To resolve this error, upload an index page to your httpdocs directory.

If you already have a home page called something else - home.html for example - you have a couple of options:

```
Rename your home page to index.html or index.php.
Set up a redirect on the index page to your real home page. See How do I redirect my site using a .htaccess file? for details.
Set a different default home page in your .htaccess file. Javascript Kit has a good example.
```

If you don't want a single page to display, but instead want to show a list of files in that directory, see Making directories browsable, solving 403 errors.

**Permissions and ownership errors**

A 403 Forbidden error can also be caused by incorrect ownership or permissions on your web content files and folders.

*source:* https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644980/why-am-i-seeing-a-403-forbidden-error-message

**I think your problem is the third point. You don't have permissions for an upload.**